# Firebase Http Oncall function

Tags: firebase

Can context part of the Firebase https onCall function be manipulated or anyone can mimic the Api request to create the header by ownself and call the Firebase https onCall firebase cloud functions using Postman.

Answer (score 2):

The full spec of the wire protocol is [in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference). Essentially you need to send a request with a Firebase ID Token in the `Authorization` header and a JSON body formatted like:

```
{
  "data": { /* your data here */ }
}
```

Comment: Haha what an underrated answer. This is exactly what I needed. Just the data wrapper.